# How to add a custom field in in joomla 2.5 article options?

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

I want to add a custom field to the article options in joomla. It can be either in the "Article Options" or in a seperate form table. I just need on single checkbox. How can this be done? I searched in the web, but it's not possible to find a working solution.

EDIT:
I need to add a custom field in the backend. I'm writing a simple plugin, where I show a js widget, when it's enabled in the article options. Therefore I need a custom field (checkbox), to check, if the widget is enabled for this article.

Comment: are you talking about frontend or backend?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention: backend.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml
```

Add your Custom Field under the

```
<fields name="attribs">
```

Tag

```
<field 
     name="your_custom_field_name"
     type="list"
     label="YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME"
     description="YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME">
         <option value="">JGLOBAL_USE_GLOBAL</option>
         <option value="0">JNO</option>
         <option value="1">JYES</option>
</field>
```

Comment: Don't over-write core code.  When you patch Joomla, it will go.

Comment: I'm writing a plugin. So it's not possible to override the core code.

Comment: Ok, then you cannot override the form by your plugin because in joomla there is no any event has been trigger while rendering the artcle adding/editing view in back-end.

Comment: Actually, you can write a plugin that does that. All you need to do is modify the form elements prior to displaying the form, and, on save, you will need to update a custom table that will include the article ID and your custom field. You will need to use the event onContentPrepareForm (see: http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentPrepareForm )